# Why is checking raycast intersections so slow in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting, pointerlock

I'm making an FPS game using Three.js.

Take a look at this code:

```js
let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycastTargets = [otherPlayer];
center = new THREE.Vector2(0,0);
function animate() {
  raycastTargets[0] = otherPlayer;
  camera.updateMatrixWorld(), raycaster.setFromCamera(center, camera);
  let intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(raycastTargets);
  intersection = intersections[0] || null;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

When this code runs, if I look at the `otherPlayer` (even when the camera is near) the page starts getting choppy/laggy.

Note that I'm using `THREE.PointerLockControls` to look around.

I don't understand why it's slowing down.

All objects are pre-defined, I'm using default JavaScript variables, everything is normal.

Why is it slowing down, and how can I stop it?

If I ran all these lines of code individually, I *doubt* it would lag.

Comment: Without seeing a live example that demonstrates the performance issue, I can only guess that `otherPlayer` has a too complex geometry. Raycasting requires to test each triangle of a model (assuming the ray already intersects with its bounding volume) so if the polycount is too high, you have to consider to simplify your model or use a BVH for speed up raycasting.

Comment: @Mugen87 True. `otherPlayer` is a glTF 2.0 realistic soldier model from sketchfab.